# Pgsql to Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregation

I have difficulty to convert the following Postgres code to snowflake. May anyone who has expertise help me in this, please?

```
select count(distinct inv.invite_id) 
filter (where invite_opened) "Invites Opened"


select case when b.onboard_initial_agents_invited_at 
then 'Initial Agents Invited'
```

For the first one I tried this, but didn't work:

```
Select count(distinct inv.invite_id) 
case when 'invites_opened' 
THEN 1 END as "Invites Opened"
```

Answer (score 1):

`select count(distinct inv.invite_id) filter (where invite_opened) "Invites Opened"` is a conditional aggregation:

```
select count(distinct CASE WHEN invite_opened THEN inv.invite_id END) AS "Invites Opened"
```

It could also be implemented with usage of [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html)(but without DISTINCT):

```
select count_if(invite_opened) AS "Invites Opened"
```